# Pseudo- andom number generation error

Tags: c++

I am the very beginner of the developing field, and I am facing a problem in Pseudo code random error in C++ language. 
I think the Error in my program is:
        { 
        srand(time (NULL));
    }

Please help me how can I remove this error and the reason of error.
The program I developed is below,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
       int lowerRange;
       int upperRange;
       lowerRange=1;
       upperRange=1;
       int secretNumber;
       int guess;
       guess=10;

       cout<<"My Student ID is BC130400789 "<<endl;
       cout<<"Enter lower range : ";
       cin>>lowerRange;

       cout<<"Enter upper range : ";
       cin>>upperRange;

       cout<<"Computer is calculating a random secret number in the given range...Done!"<<endl;
       cout<<"\nPlease guesss the secret number in the range ["<<lowerRange<<" - "<<upperRange<<"]: ";
       cin>>guess;

       if(guess<10)
       {
                    cout<<"You won! You guess the correct number.. ";
                    }
        else 
        {
             cout<<"Oooppsss...Your entered number is too high...Computer won"<<endl<<endl;

            }


            { srand(time (NULL));}


             secretNumber = rand()%10+1;
             cout<<"Secret number was: "<<secretNumber<<endl<<endl;
             }
                         system("pause");
       }
```

Comment: use [<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)

Comment: It would help to say what error you get.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main()`. Consistent indentation would tell you very quickly why your code isn't compiling. Showing us code that fails to compile without showing us the error message is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. main HAS TO return int
2. rand() is defined in cstdlib which you don't include
3. You also need to include ctime for time function
4. As said by G. Samaras you shouldn't use system("pause") (also you don't include required header for it) and you have mismatched `{}`.

I would also recommend you reading something about code formatting.

Comment: I can't understand where i used {} mismatched?? Please help me. and the error i am facing is still in  srand(time (NULL));

Comment: G. Samaras said exatly where you have one extra `}`

Comment: I remove one extra } also removed system pause but the same error exists

Comment: Have you fixed the rest of things that I mentioned? Also post the error, it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: yes i tried , basically am required to generate random numbers, when I compile my program it gives error in line where code is, that is 34 line,  srand(time (NULL));

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I got srand(time(NULL)); cant not be used as a funtion

Comment: Anyone can understand what I said? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket at the end. Remove this and the `system("pause");` and you will get no errors. Also `main()` usually returns an `int`, thus make it `int main()`.

---

[system(“pause”); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong)

Comment: There's an extra `}` at the end, but just removing it won't fix the problem; it would leave the `system("pause");` at file scope, which is illegal.

Comment: That's why I have the link, but yes I am not clear, editting.

Comment: The link asserts that `system("pause");` is a bad idea (which is frankly questionable, and certainly isn't the cause of the OP's problem).